# Time Blocks from Hour Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hoping someone can help as i'm racking my brain trying to figure it out.

I have a new system i'm creating that pulls off the time a user is available and unavailable, I have two arrays:

Available:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00:00:00
            [1] => 01:00:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01:00:00
            [1] => 02:00:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03:00:00
            [1] => 04:00:00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 04:00:00
            [1] => 05:00:00
        )

)
```

Unavailable:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 02:00:00
            [1] => 03:00:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 05:00:00
            [1] => 06:00:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 06:00:00
            [1] => 07:00:00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 07:00:00
            [1] => 08:00:00
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08:00:00
            [1] => 09:00:00
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 09:00:00
            [1] => 10:00:00
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10:00:00
            [1] => 11:00:00
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11:00:00
            [1] => 12:00:00
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12:00:00
            [1] => 13:00:00
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13:00:00
            [1] => 14:00:00
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14:00:00
            [1] => 15:00:00
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15:00:00
            [1] => 16:00:00
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16:00:00
            [1] => 17:00:00
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17:00:00
            [1] => 18:00:00
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18:00:00
            [1] => 19:00:00
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19:00:00
            [1] => 20:00:00
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20:00:00
            [1] => 21:00:00
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21:00:00
            [1] => 22:00:00
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22:00:00
            [1] => 23:00:00
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23:00:00
            [1] => 00:00:00
        )

)
```

Each array has hour slots, eg. 12am-1am, 1am-2am etc.

But I'm trying to trying to find a way to group the hours, eg.

Available: 00:00:00 - 02:00:00 and 03:00:00 - 05:00:00 
and 
Unavailable: 05:00:00 - 00:00:00

Can anyone suggest any solutions?

Thanks.

-EDIT- Just to clarify what I'm after:
This is 1 person for 1 day. If they have put they are available between 6pm and 10pm it will come through to me as hours eg. 18:00:00 - 19:00:00, 19:00:00 - 20:00:00 etc. But I just need 18:00:00 - 22:00:00. Thanks.

I can also use this array:

```
Array
```

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00:00:00
            [1] => 01:00:00
            [2] => A
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 01:00:00
        [1] => 02:00:00
        [2] => A
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 02:00:00
        [1] => 03:00:00
        [2] => U
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 03:00:00
        [1] => 04:00:00
        [2] => A
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 04:00:00
        [1] => 05:00:00
        [2] => A
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 05:00:00
        [1] => 06:00:00
        [2] => U
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 06:00:00
        [1] => 07:00:00
        [2] => U
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => 07:00:00
        [1] => 08:00:00
        [2] => U
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => 08:00:00
        [1] => 09:00:00
        [2] => U
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => 09:00:00
        [1] => 10:00:00
        [2] => U
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10:00:00
        [1] => 11:00:00
        [2] => U
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [0] => 11:00:00
        [1] => 12:00:00
        [2] => U
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [0] => 12:00:00
        [1] => 13:00:00
        [2] => U
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [0] => 13:00:00
        [1] => 14:00:00
        [2] => U
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [0] => 14:00:00
        [1] => 15:00:00
        [2] => U
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15:00:00
        [1] => 16:00:00
        [2] => U
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [0] => 16:00:00
        [1] => 17:00:00
        [2] => U
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [0] => 17:00:00
        [1] => 18:00:00
        [2] => U
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [0] => 18:00:00
        [1] => 19:00:00
        [2] => U
    )

[19] => Array
    (
        [0] => 19:00:00
        [1] => 20:00:00
        [2] => U
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [0] => 20:00:00
        [1] => 21:00:00
        [2] => U
    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [0] => 21:00:00
        [1] => 22:00:00
        [2] => U
    )

[22] => Array
    (
        [0] => 22:00:00
        [1] => 23:00:00
        [2] => U
    )

[23] => Array
    (
        [0] => 23:00:00
        [1] => 00:00:00
        [2] => U
    )
```

)

But I just need to group them up. Thanks.

Comment: Are you generating them or you have them in an array already ??

Comment: I have the array already. I need to process it.

Comment: So you have 2 arrays you want to convert it to one ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to end up with a formatted string output.

You have to iterate over the array keys and check both arrays. Assuming that all users are present in array `$available` and `$unavailable` you might try something like this:

```
$userSlots = array();

foreach(array_keys($available) as $userKey) {

    $userSlots[ $userKey ] = 'Available: ';

    foreach ($available[ $userKey ] as $slot) {
       $userSlots[ $userKey ] .= $slot[ 0 ] . ' - ' . $slot[ 1 ] . ', ';
    }

    $aggregatedSlots .= 'Unavailable: ';

    foreach ($unavailable[ $userKey ] as $slot) {
       $userSlots[ $userKey ] .= $slot[ 0 ] . ' - ' . $slot[ 1 ] . ', ';
    }
}
```

You'll get an array with userKeys as keys and formatted "availability" strings as values. Of course some intelligent checks and string modification should be added to avoid trailing commas.

Comment: Oh sorry, some stuff was "hacked down" too fast. I added corrections in names and string concatenation and expect it to be (formally) correct now.

Comment: Hi Matze, Thanks for the reply. This is seems to output virtually the same, but puts the user key in front of it. You may have got the wrong end of the stick. This is 1 person for 1 day. If they have put they are available between 6pm and 10pm it will come through to me as hours eg. 18:00:00 - 19:00:00, 19:00:00 - 20:00:00 etc. But I just need 18:00:00 - 22:00:00. Does that make sense? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand  .. you want to split array into two groups

- A:  Available
- U: Unavailable

You can just use array filter

```
$avialable =  array_filter($array,function($var) { return $var[2] == "A" ; });
$unavialabe =  array_filter($array,function($var) { return $var[2] == "U" ; });
```